# querySelectorAll() targeting rel="me" attribute AND href attribute containing "12345"

Tags: javascript

I have a very specific situation here that I can't find anywhere else.

I need to point to a `<link>` element that contains the `rel="me"` attribute AND an `href="https://www.example.com/profile/12345"` attribute that CONTAINS `12345`.

```
<link rel="me" href="https://www.example.com/profile/12345"/>
```

I tried with `document.querySelectorAll()` but I don't know how to format it to make the `AND` operator work.

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('[rel="me"], a[href*=123456]')[0])
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a CSS selector "AND" is just not using a combinator at all.

If you have a type (or universal) selector, it has to go first.

The type selector to select `<link>` elements is `link` not `a`.

```
link[rel="me"][href*="12345"]
```

If you want the first match, use `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()[0]`

```js
const el = document.querySelector('link[rel="me"][href*="12345"]');
console.log(el);
```

```html
<link rel="me" href="https://www.example.com/profile/12345"/>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the heads up :) You only forgot the quotes betweeen `12345`.